# WooCommerce Coupon Field Extension

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I added new custom post type 'giftcard' and extended WooCommerce simple product by adding checkbox 'Gift Card'

Whenever order status changed to 'processing' and it contains product type giftcard, it creates new giftcard post by following code

```
function status_order_processing( $order_id ) {
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
   $items = $order->get_items();

   foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $is_gift_card = get_post_meta( $item['product_id'], '_woo_giftcard', true );

    if($is_gift_card == 'yes'){
$token = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
            $token = bin2hex($token);
            $hyphen = chr(45);
    $uuid =  substr($token, 0, 8).$hyphen
            .substr($token, 8, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($token,12, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($token,16, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($token,20,12);

   $gift_card = array(
    'post_title'    => $uuid,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'     => 'giftcard',
);
   $gift_card_id = wp_insert_post( $gift_card, $wp_error );
   update_post_meta( $gift_card_id, 'woo_gift_card_amount', (int)$item['total'] );

}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'status_order_processing' );
```

New post name is a token generated in above code and save item total in meta field 'woo_gift_card_amount'.

Is there any way if I enter giftcard post type token in coupon field and it subtracts amount from Order amount according to meta field 'woo_gift_card_amount' of that post.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Coupons are also a custom post. To use your gift card token/uuid as woocommerce coupon, you will need to insert it as a new post in `shop_coupon` post type.

A quick example (this should go inside your `status_order_processing` function, or you can use separate function -  whichever way suits you):

```
$coupon_code = $uuid;
$amount = (int)$item['total'];
$discount_type = 'fixed_cart'; //available types: fixed_cart, percent, fixed_product, percent_product

$coupon = array(
    'post_title' => $coupon_code,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'shop_coupon'
);

$new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );

if ( $new_coupon_id ) {
    //add coupon/post meta
    update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'discount_type', $discount_type);
    update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'coupon_amount', $amount);
    //update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'expiry_date', $expiry_date);
    //update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit', '1');
    //update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'no');
    //update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', '' );
    //update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'exclude_product_ids', '' );
    //update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit', '' );
    //update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'expiry_date', '' );
    //update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'apply_before_tax', 'yes' );
    //update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'free_shipping', 'no' );
}
```

Comment: The reason I added new custom post type is, I have an admin page where I display all the posts (gift cards) information. I saved these as custom fields, I know I can add those custom fields if I use default shop_coupon post type. How can I differentiate default coupons and those that added dynamically as you stated in above code, the other problem is amount tracking, for example if someone has $1000 amount gift card and made purchase of $500, the coupon amount should update to $500 and usable again. Is something that I could do with default coupons?

Comment: No, default coupon can't do it. You will need to keep track of amount used in order, save it in DB, and subtract on next usage. It seems like you are looking for voucher system. There are several plugins available to achieve this. I think it's too vast to describe that system here in details.